# Netlogo 5.3.1 - export-world not working and not producing any files

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to use export-world with NetLogo to get my data out and into an excel file (I want to run stats on how many times my agents walk over sites in a model). It initially worked once with the "export-world" command, but it stopped working.

I saw that this command over-writes the initial file, so following the Netlogo dictionary, I changed the code to read as below:

```
to go

   move

   check-if-site

   tick

   if ticks = 100 [stop
    
    export-world (word "results " date-and-time ".csv") ]



end
```

However, now, no CSV document is being created at all.

Thanks for any help!

**Update** - I tried shifting the stop position, but it created the following error:

```
export-world: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

error while observer running EXPORT-WORLD
called by procedure GO
called by Button 'go'

**UPDATE 2 -**

Thank you so much for that extra line of code!

While the model worked with the new line of code, I couldn't find the export file anywhere (admittedly, this could simply be due to user error on my end).

However - I found that if I ran it with the line of code, saved it after the model finished, and then used export world from the File menu, it appeared as a CSV file.

Thank you so much again for all your help!

Comment: What value do you have stored in date-and-time? The rest of your formula and syntax is correct so the new problem has to lie there.

Comment: Scrap that, i didn't know date-and-time was a Netlogo primitive. The problem is that date-and-time contains a `:` and a file-name can't contain `:`'s (just try changing a random file-name to include one of them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your scheduling of events. `stop` happens before `export-world` and immediately exists the go procedure, therefore `export-world` will never happen.
If you include a `stop` within any procedure, make sure to always write it down after the last thing you want to happen.

**EDIT AFTER UPDATE**
A second problem you have is that `date-and-time` gives you a string of the following format: `"01:19:36.685 PM 19-Sep-2002"`. This string includes a `:`, which is an invalid character for file-names. You can either choose a different way to name your outputs, or you can use `date-and-time` but remove the offending characters.

```
to go

   move

   check-if-site

   tick

   if ticks = 100 [

      let new-date-and-time replace-item 2 date-and-time ";"
      set new-date-and-time replace-item 5 new-date-and-time ";"
      export-world (word "results " new-date-and-time ".csv") 

      stop
   ]

end
```

This gives you a file with the following name: results 01;19;36.685 PM 19-Sep-2002.csv.
You can of course do the replacement to whatever character you want, as long as it is a valid one.